# What is HttpContext.Current.Response

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a new endpoint to download a file from the server. Got the example from https://forums.asp.net/t/2010544.aspx?Download+files+from+website+using+Asp+net+c+ and this is what I ended up:

```
[Route("{id}/file")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetFile(int id)
{
    var filePath = $"C:\\Static\\File_{id}.pdf";

    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    var data = new WebClient().DownloadData(filePath);

    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();

    return Ok(response);
}
```

But I wasn't sure if I need all these:

```
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();
```

What do these do?

Comment: The method names are pretty self explanatory... if you hover over them you'll get their definition within VS. Otherwise they will 100% be documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clearheaders(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did you press F1 while taking the caret over the method names?

Comment: very useful tips!! thanks all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response object is the object containing everything relative to the response the client will receive from the server once the current request is served back.

```
response.Clear(); -> Will clear the content of the body of the response ( any html for example that was supposed to be served back, you can remove this)
response.ClearContent(); -> will clear any content in the response ( that is why you can remove the previous Clear call i think )
response.ClearHeaders(); -> Clears all headers asscociated with the response. (For example a header might tell the client there is 'encoding:gzip')
response.Buffer = true; -> enables response buffer
response.BinaryWrite(data); -> Appends your binary data to the content of the response( you cleared it earlier so now only this is contained)
response.End(); -> Terminates the current response handling and returns the response to the client.
```

Look up more stuff and better explanations [here!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse)