# HttpResponse.ClearContent() keeps returning Html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm Trying to make a downloadable file with corpus my bytes variable. However, even if I try to cancel out the HttpResponse body and header (also trying response.Clear()) this keep me returning what I want (bytes) BUT also the html in the end. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
string value = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName); // name of file
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", value);
response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
   stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
}
```

I'm following the indications made also in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300334/what-is-httpcontext-current-response)

Comment: Perhaps you need to call [`Response.End()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end?view=netframework-4.8) as well?

Comment: It raises this exception if I use End()

System.Threading.ThreadAbortException occurred
  HResult=0x80131530
  Message=Thread was being aborted.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at [<ascx file path>]

Comment: Yes, that is correct, is that a problem? That is expected.

Comment: The code doesn't show where `bytes` comes from. It's likely that you're reading the response into `bytes` before you clear it. If you've read the response and it's stored in `bytes`, clearing the response won't change what's stored in `bytes`. If I'm misunderstanding perhaps you can show where `bytes` comes from. Is the expectation that it will be empty?